# Makefile can't find a target that is already there

Tags: c, makefile

So I've got the following folder structure

```
makefile
src/my_lib.c
src/myhead.h
```

and I'm trying to compile *my_lib.c* with the header *myhead.h* as a library. This is the *makefile*. I attempt to put the *obj* files in *OBJFOLDER* and the compiled library in the *OUTPUTFOLDER*

```
PLUGNAME=my_lib

SOURCEFOLDER=src
OUTPUTFOLDER=bin
OBJFOLDER=bin/obj

OBJS=$(PLUGNAME).o
DEPS=myhead.h

# Configuration finishes here

_OBJS = $(patsubst %,$(OBJFOLDER)/%,$(OBJS))
_DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(SOURCEFOLDER)/%,$(DEPS))

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    EXT = .dll
else
    UNAME_S := $(shell uname -s)
    ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Linux)
        EXT = .so
    endif
endif

all : $(OUTPUTFOLDER)/$(PLUGNAME)$(EXT)

$(OUTPUTFOLDER)/$(PLUGNAME)$(EXT) : $(_OBJS)
    gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -shared -o $@ $(_OBJS)

$(OBJFOLDER)/%.o: $(SOURCEFOLDER)/%.c $(_DEPS)
    mkdir -p $(OUTPUTFOLDER)
    mkdir -p $(OBJFOLDER)
    gcc $(foreach d, $(INC), -I$d) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean

clean :
    rm -f $(OBJFOLDER)/*.o $(OUTPUTFOLDER)/$(PLUGNAME)$(EXT)                             $(SOURCEFOLDER)/TSDRPlugin.h
```

When I do *make all* it fails

```
make: *** No rule to make target `bin/obj/my_lib.o', needed by `bin/
my_lib.dll'.  Stop.
```

I have no idea how this could be possible since I already have defined

```
 $(OBJFOLDER)/%.o: $(SOURCEFOLDER)/%.c $(_DEPS)
```

Strangely if I change the above line in the *makefile*, to

```
 bin/obj/my_lib.o: $(SOURCEFOLDER)/%.c $(_DEPS)
```

I now get

```
 make: *** No rule to make target `src/%.c', needed by `bin/obj/my_lib.o'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that header was missing... Stupid mistake on my side.

I overlooked it, because this was a snippet from a longer makefile that was supposed to copy over the header but it didn't which means that this line was outputting the error. Stupid me...

Answer (score 2):

Your second error is because by removing the `%` in the target you've turned this into an explicit rule, not a pattern rule.  So, the `%` in the prerequisite is not replaced.

Your first error means that for some reason make is deciding that your pattern rule doesn't match.  This means, usually, that make can't find and doesn't know how to create one of the prerequisites.  I recommend you run make with the `-d` flag and see why make decides your rule doesn't apply.

What version of GNU make are you using?  Some very old versions would not match pattern rules if the directory that the target was to be placed into didn't exist already.

Comment: I tried creating the directories. Still no good. This is the output of *make -d* http://pastebin.com/qrAd7bSQ

Comment: I'm using the make from MinGW on Windows 8 C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe

Comment: Discovered, the problem was that the header file was missing... This is actually a snippet from a longer makefile. It was my fault. I have asked a moderator to close the topic... Thanks anyways.